# My app is not parsing the JSON response

Tags: ios, json, nsurlconnection

I am very new for ios and in my project I am using `NSUrlConnection` for integrating services but when I send request to server I got an empty response and this error:

> JSONValue failed. Error trace is: (
>       "Error Domain=org.brautaset.JSON.ErrorDomain Code=11 \"Unexpected end of string\" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unexpected end of string}"
>   )

but when I check in post man client response is coming from server

but why response not coming in my app please help me some one.

### My dicitionary request:-

```
dictionary is {
    MedicaidId = 101229518299;
    coriders =     (
        2870862
    );
    escort =     {
        name = "";
        relation = 2;
    };
    schUrgentCare = 0;
    test = tripComments;
    transportMode = Regular;
    tripDate = "10/02/2016 - 09:32 PM";
    tripLegs =     (
                {
            ApptTime = "10/02/2016 - 09:32 PM";
            TerritoryId = 3;
            TripLegType = 4;
            destination =             {
                Address1 = "335 VANDALIA ST";
                Address2 = "";
                City = LAPAZ;
                PhoneNo = 5747842191;
                ProviderId = 0;
                State = IN;
                Zip = 46537;
            };
            source =             {
                Address1 = "335 VANDALIA ST";
                Address2 = "";
                City = LAPAZ;
                PhoneNo = 5747842191;
                ProviderId = 1;
                State = IN;
                Zip = 46537;
            };
        }
    );
    tripNotes =     {
        HasCarSeat = 0;
        HasSplEquipment = 0;
        NeedLiftVan = 0;
        TransferWheelChair = 0;
        WheelChairCanFold = 1;
        WheelChairCanNotFold = 1;
    };
    urgentCare = 0;
}
```

### my code:-

```
-(void)serviceCalling :(NSDictionary*)mydictionary{



    NSError *error = nil;

    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:mydictionary

                                                       options:kNilOptions

                                                         error:&error];

    NSString *urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@Trip/Create",kServerBaseURL];

    NSLog(@"urlStr --->> %@",urlStr);


    NSURL *serviceUrl=[NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];


    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:serviceUrl];


    [request setTimeoutInterval:120];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    [request setValue:AccessToken forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

    [request setValue:@"json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Data-Type"];

    [request setHTTPBody:jsonData];

    NSURLConnection *connectionManager = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];


    if (connectionManager) {

        NSLog(@"connected");
    }

    else{
        NSLog(@"not connected");
    }
 }

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{

    [downloadedMutableData appendData:data];

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{

    [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];

    if (error.code == NSURLErrorTimedOut){

         NSLog(@"REquest time out");
    }

    else{

        NSLog(@"Response --->> ERRORRRRRR");

    }

}

// This method is call,when server response is success

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{


    [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];

    NSDictionary *responeDict = [[[NSString alloc]initWithData:downloadedMutableData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] JSONValue];

    NSLog(@"Response --->> %@",responeDict);

}
```

Comment: I'm confused about the dictionary you posted. Is that what is being returned from the server? Or is that what should be converted into json and returned from the server?

Comment: i am sending that dic to server  then i got exception like above what i posted

Comment: Ah, I see. You're posting to the server, not fetching from it. May want to clarify that in your question.

Comment: But in postman client respone is coming

Comment: Try NSJSONSerialization. Converting to an NSString is unnecessary and may fail - JSON doesn't have to be UTF-8.

Comment: please edit my code i am very new for this technology